# How can I write block matrix like this?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Can someone please help me out in writing this matrix?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Thus the matrix representation~$\mathcal{L}$ under the basis is
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A &   &        & 0 \\
      & A &        &   \\
      &   & \ddots &   \\
    0 &   &        & A
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
The desired result follows immediately.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `nicematrix` is a great extension too!

Answer (score 3):

In Plain TeX, your document looks like this:

```
Thus the matrix representation~$\cal L$ under the basis is
$$
  \pmatrix{ A &   &        & 0 \cr
              & A &        &   \cr
              &   & \ddots &   \cr
            0 &   &        & A }
$$
The desired result follows immediately.
\bye
```